# Showing partial derivatives are constant on connected domain, means $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis

I know this question has been asked before, I just want to know how I can use this approach to successfully complete the proof.

Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open, $\text{connected}$ set.  Prove that, if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\textbf{x}) = 0$ for all $i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $\textbf{x} \in A$, then $f$ is constant.

Attempt:Choose $r>0$ such that $B_r(x) \subset A$. Let $\textbf{h}$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||\textbf{h}||<r$. By the mean value theorem there is a $\theta \in (0,1)$ with $f(\textbf{x}+\textbf{h})-f(\textbf{x})=\langle \nabla f(\textbf{x}+\theta \textbf{h}),\textbf{h}\rangle$. But $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)=0$ for each $i$. Thus $f(\textbf{x}+\textbf{h})=f(\textbf{x})$. Since this holds for all $\textbf{x}+\textbf{h} \in B_r(x)$, $f$ is constant on $B_r(x)$. So $f(y)=c$ for all $y \in B_r(x)$. Now I know $B_r(x) \subset f^{-1}\{c\}$ but I cannot figure out how to show that $B_r(x)$ must also be closed and equal to all of $A$ by connectedness Any ideas?

Edit: Now I am noticing some issues with my attempt based on the mean value theorem I am using, are there any ways to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ be the connected open set in question, and suppose we have $x \in U$. We wish to show $V = \{y \in U | f(y) = f(x)\}$ is open.

Indeed, consider such a $y$ and take $r$ such that $B_r(y) \subseteq U$. Then consider $z \in B_r(y)$. We can get from $y$ to $z$ by taking a path where each segment of the path is parallel to an axis. Thus, along each segment, $f$ must be constant (since its partial derivative in the relevant direction is 0). Then we see that $f(y) = f(z) = f(x)$. Thus, $B_r(y) \subseteq V$. Then $V$ is indeed open.

But it is also the case that $W = \{y \in U | f(y) \neq f(x)\}$ is open, by continuity. And we know that $V \cup W = U$ and $V$ has an element - namely, $x$. And clearly, $V \cap W = \emptyset$. Therefore, it must be the case that $V = U$.

In that case, for all $y \in U$, $f(y) = f(x)$.